# Alternatives to ZIP for combining many files into one on Windows using .NET

Tags: c#, .net, file, zip

Im looking for methods to combine files including their name and relative path into one single file. A folder disguised as a file. I don't need any compression or encryption. Just the file data including some binary metadata attached to each file.

It would be great if this file was possible to open/inspect/unpack with a standard file browser in Windows such as with regular zip-files.

Yes I could use zip. But I'm researching alternatives and I would prefer a simple method I could implement myself in C#/.NET.

**UPDATE**

I've researched this some more and came across Microsoft's Structured Storage format. It looked promising at first but it seemes to be an obsolete format, replaced with the Open Package Format. And then I found out about the TAR-format. It seemes to be the most basic format. But I'm not sure yet if I can add any custom metadata to the entries with TAR.

**UPDATE**

I went with DotNetZip at the end anyway...

Comment: *Why* do you need alternatives to common archiving formats (zip, 7z, rar, tar etc.)? They are widely supported and all support a "no-compression" mode to only store the files without compressing them. If you specify your requirements we can help more easily. Of course you can invent your own format, but it will be inferior in every aspect wrt existing solutions. So unless it's for personal education, stick to what's there.

Comment: There is no simpler method, nor any that will work better for packing files. As Andre mentions, you can just use archives to store files, and some (such as RAR) provide useful splitting and data-validation and recovery features. ZIP and TAR are both rather simple formats as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not use zip? You can use a third party library, like [dotnetzip](http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/), to make the code easy to write. And, as you mentioned, Windows handles zip files well.

Answer (score 0):

If you have specific reason to search an alternative to ZIP, take a look on virtual file systems, eg. [CodeBase File System](http://www.codebase.com/products/filesystem/) or our [Solid File System](http://www.eldos.com/solfs/solfs-vs-zip.php). Solid File System lets you add alternate data streams (like in NTFS) or tags (small chunks of binary or text data) to each file or directory. And with OS edition of SolFS you can make the filesystem visible to Windows (including Explorer and third-party applications).

I must admit that while virtual file systems are easy to use (easier than ZIP), they are commercial products (I didn't see free virtual file system implementations yet).